# Left outer join for the same table works wrong on redshift

Tags: sql, left-join, amazon-redshift

I need to perform left outer join on the same table. As a result I expect all requested columns from table 1 and only those from table 2 which joined.

Here is how to reproduce:

```
drop table nz_mri_survey_agg;

create table mri_survey_agg (
HOUSEHOLD_PERSON_HK integer,
MRI_DICTIONARY_ID   INTEGER,
rank integer);

insert into mri_survey_agg values (651694412, 2127115057, 36903);
insert into mri_survey_agg values (647638311, 1293574238, 35413);
insert into mri_survey_agg values (647638311, -2076426274, 35413);
insert into mri_survey_agg values (651694412, -2076426274, 35413);
insert into mri_survey_agg values (651694412, -2051582071, 35411);
insert into mri_survey_agg values (647638311, -1747375415, 35613);
insert into mri_survey_agg values (647638311, 1234567, 35610);
```

Here is the query:

```
select distinct t1.household_person_hk, t2.mri_dictionary_id 
from mri_survey_agg t1 
left outer join (
    select household_person_hk, mri_dictionary_id from mri_survey_agg 
    where mri_dictionary_id in 
    (-2076426274, -2051582071, -1747375415)) t2 
on t1.household_person_hk = t2.household_person_hk;
```

I expect the next output:

```
household_person_hk mri_dictionary_id
651694412           -2051582071
647638311           -2076426274
651694412           -2076426274
647638311           -1747375415
647638311            <NaN>
```

The output is:

```
household_person_hk mri_dictionary_id
651694412           -2051582071
647638311           -2076426274
651694412           -2076426274
647638311           -1747375415
```

It works perfect on Postgres, but doesn't give me expected results on Redshift.

Appreciate for any hints.

**UPD**: Actually, the actual output is correct!

Comment: Your actual output looks correct to me.  Can you explain why you're expecting to get `647638311` with a NULL when you're also getting `647638311` with a non-NULL value?  Wouldn't you need to specify `mri_dictionary_id in (-2076426274, -2051582071, -1747375415) or mri_dictionary_id is null`?

Comment: you are right, since distinct will not give 647638311 with NULL. That confused me initially but now it is ok.

Comment: Nah, it doesn't have anything to do with DISTINCT.  It's how an OUTER JOIN works.  The only way you'd get the expected results I mentioned is if you added `or mri_dictionary_id is null` to the inner query *and* the table in the inner query had a record with `(647638311, NULL)`.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your code on Postgres and it returns four rows, which is correct.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c079e/1) is a SQL Fiddle, which is now working.

Note that your query can more easily be written as:

```
select distinct t1.household_person_hk, t2.mri_dictionary_id 
from mri_survey_agg t1 left outer join
     mri_survey_agg t2
     on t1.household_person_hk = t2.household_person_hk and
        t2.mri_dictionary_id in (-2076426274, -2051582071, -1747375415);
```

Comment: @Alex . . . A remarkably similar version with fixed typos does work (the correct version is there now).